# Prove that differential equation $y' = 1 + \sqrt[5]{y-x}$ has exactly one solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given differential equation $y' = 1 + \sqrt[5]{y-x}$
Prove that through every point of region $(x-2)^2 + (y-4)^2=1$ passes exactly one solution of given equation

In my opinion, we have to use Cauchy theorem on several regions, union of which gives initial region, but i'm stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the function $f$ of the variable $(x,y)$, defined on $\Bbb R^2$ by
$$
f(x,y)= 1+(y-x)^{1/5}\ .
$$
Fix $\delta >0$.

We would like to apply [Picard-Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for $f$ and any point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the open region
$$
D_\delta:=\{\ (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\ :\ \delta < y-x\ \}\ ,
$$
which is the half-plane containing $(2,4)$ with boundary parallel and
at distance  $\delta$ from the line $y=x$. The given function is continuous in $x$. It remains to insure $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz continuous in the variable $y$. For this, we build the differential $f'_y$ of $f$ w.r.t. the variable $y$, it is
$$
f'_y(x,y)
=
\frac 15 (y-x)^{-4/5}
=
\frac 1{5(y-x)^{4/5}}
\ .
$$
Observe that this expression is bounded, since the distance from the closure of $D_\delta$ to the line $x=y$ is $\delta>0$. The reason to restrict to $_\delta$ was to avoid $(3,3)$:

[[image: Distance from the half-plane <span class=]$B_\delta$ to the line $x=y$, dan_fulea" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYYea.png)

We have $y-x\ge \delta$, so
$$
\|f'_y\|\le \frac 1{5\delta^{4/5}}\ .
$$
The conditions for Picard-Lindelöf for $f$ on $D_\delta$ are thus satisfied, we have a unique solution locally "through" each point $(x_0,y_0)$ in $D_\delta$. And the regions $D_\delta$ are covering the given ball around $(2,4)$ with radius one, except for the point $(3,3)$. So we need to consider this point separately. The equation to be solved is
$$
(y-x)'=(y-x)^{1/5}\ ,\ y(3)=3\ .
$$
One solution is $y=x$. We have to check if  there is no other.
The problem begins here, we find all solutions below.

---

Consider  an other solution $y:(3-a,3+a)\to \Bbb R$. (We want to get the solution or a contradiction soon.)

Let $b\ge 0$ be maximal so that $y=x$ on $[3-b,3+b]$. The case $b>0$ is not possible, since then $y(3\pm b)=3\pm b$, $y=x$ is still a local solution, and with a similar argument as above (possibly for a half-plane on the other side) we obtain a contradiction to the uniqueness.

So $b=0$.
And we have $y\ne x$ on some strictly monotone sequence inside $(3-a,3+a)$ converging to $3$. Then locally around a point $x_0$ from this sequence we obtain successively:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(y-x)'&=(y-x)^{1/5}\ ,\\
(y-x)'(y-x)^{-1/5}&=1\ ,\\
\Big(\ (y-x)^{4/5}\ \Big)'&=\frac 45\ ,\\
(y-x)^{4/5}&=\frac 45x+C(x_0)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Here $C(x_0)$ is a constant function living on the maximal interval inside $\{x\ :\ y(x)\ne x\}$ that contains $x_0$.

If $x_0<3$, then the L.H.S. is $>0$, so the R.H.S. is $>0$ and it remains so locally to the right of $x_0$ on the interval $(x_0,3)$. So also in the point $3$. But there the L.H.S. is $(y(3)-3)^{4/5}=0$. A contradiction. This implies that we have $y(x)=x$ for $x\le 3$.

Let us consider now the case $x_0>3$. Then again, on the interval $(x_0,3+a)$ the R.H.S. remains $>0$, so the formula remains true as the unique possibility to extend the solution. This implies
$$
(y-x)^{4/5}=\frac 45 x+C\ ,\ x\in[3,3+a)\ ,
$$
for a suitable constant $C$. (We can define $C$ as the limit of $C(x_0)$ for $x_0\searrow 3$.) This and $y(3)=3$ determines $C$, so that we have
$$
(y-x)^{4/5}=\frac 45(x-3)  ,\ x\in[3,3+a)\ ,
$$
We extract the formula for $y$ on $[3,3+a)$ and
consider the only possibility
$$
y(x)=
\begin{cases}
x &\text{ for }x\le 3\ ,\\
x+\left(\frac 45\right)^{5/4}(x-3)^{5/4} &\text{ for }x\ge 3\ .
\end{cases}
$$
We observe that the two branches do fit together into a $\mathcal C^1$ function.

So the claimed property fails for the point $(3,3)$.